# PySide2 OpenGL error when using custom QSurfaceFormat

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, pyside2, pyopengl

I'm using `QSurfaceFormat` to explicitly define **OpenGL Core profile** and set minor/major versions. The thing is, assignment of a custom surface format gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artem/PycharmProjects/PolyEdit3D/PolyEdit3D/Widgets/PlyViewport.py", line 22, in initializeGL
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  File "/home/artem/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1280,
    description = b'invalid enumerant',
    baseOperation = glEnable,
    cArguments = (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,)
)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artem/PycharmProjects/PolyEdit3D/PolyEdit3D/Widgets/PlyViewport.py", line 69, in paintGL
    gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
  File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 318, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "/home/artem/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glDrawElements,
    pyArgs = (
        GL_TRIANGLES,
        6,
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
        c_void_p(None),
    ),
    cArgs = (
        GL_TRIANGLES,
        6,
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
        c_void_p(None),
    ),
    cArguments = (
        GL_TRIANGLES,
        6,
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
        c_void_p(None),
    )
)
```

As you can see there's an error in `gl.glEnable(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` and other simple things. Without specifying `QSurfaceFormat` everything works like a charm.

Here's my surface format class:

```py
class GLSurfaceFormat(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GLSurfaceFormat, self).__init__()
        self.__initSurface()

    def __initSurface(self):
        self.setRenderableType(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.OpenGL)
        self.setMinorVersion(3)
        self.setMajorVersion(4)
        self.setProfile(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.CoreProfile)
        self.setColorSpace(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.sRGBColorSpace)
        self.setSwapBehavior(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.DoubleBuffer)
```

Here's how I assign it:

```py
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
    QSurfaceFormat.setDefaultFormat(GLSurfaceFormat())

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
```

Could you tell me, is there any mistake in `QSurfaceFormat` usage or maybe there's something else?

**!UPDATE!**
Here's a quick example where you can reproduce the same behavior:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from OpenGL import GL as gl
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import sys
import glm

class PlyViewportWidget(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlyViewportWidget, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.vao = None
        self.vbo = None
        self.ebo = None
        self.shaderProg = None
        self.isWireframe = False

    def initializeGL(self):
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1)

        with open("fragment.glsl", 'r') as f:
            fragment = compileShader(f.read(), gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        with open("vertex.glsl", "r") as f:
            vertex = compileShader(f.read(), gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        self.shaderProg = compileProgram(vertex, fragment)

        vertices = np.array(
            [
                0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                -0.5, 0.5, 0.0
            ], dtype=ctypes.c_float
        )
        indices = np.array(
            [
                0, 1, 3,
                1, 2, 3
            ], dtype=ctypes.c_uint
        )

        self.vbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        self.ebo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ebo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 3 * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0)

        gl.glUseProgram(self.shaderProg)

    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        trans = self.getTransformMatrix()
        #u_transform = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaderProg, "u_transform")
        #gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_transform, 1, gl.GL_FALSE, u_transform)

        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

    def resizeGL(self, w:int, h:int):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event:QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        self.makeCurrent()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z and not self.isWireframe:
            gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_LINE)
            self.isWireframe = True
            self.update()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z and self.isWireframe:
            gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_FILL)
            self.isWireframe = False
            self.update()

        event.accept()

    def getTransformMatrix(self):
        return glm.rotate(glm.mat4(1.0), glm.radians(90.0), glm.vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))


class GLSurfaceFormat(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GLSurfaceFormat, self).__init__()
        self.__initSurface()

    def __initSurface(self):
        self.setRenderableType(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.OpenGL)
        self.setMinorVersion(3)
        self.setMajorVersion(4)
        self.setProfile(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.CoreProfile)
        self.setColorSpace(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.sRGBColorSpace)
        self.setSwapBehavior(QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.DoubleBuffer)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
    # Uncomment to get this damn error!!!
    #QtGui.QSurfaceFormat.setDefaultFormat(GLSurfaceFormat())

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PlyViewportWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`vertex.glsl`

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

`fragment.glsl`

```c
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the error has anything to do with the code shown.  Instead it looks like you are simply calling `glEnable` with an invalid enum value of `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` somewhere in `PlyViewport.py` .

Comment: @G.M., `PlyViewport.py` is  subclass from `QOpenGLWidget`. I use `glEnable` with a **proper** enum in `initializeGL` method (which is correct due to QT API docs). By the way, I've mentioned that my app works perfect. I can see this behavior only after specifying `QSurfaceFormat`

Comment: Why do you invoke `gl.glBindVertexArray(0)`?

Comment: @Rabbid76, This is from learnopengl.com code snippet. Author unbinds VAO there and I didn't change anything. Take a look at line 136: https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/2.2.hello_triangle_indexed/hello_triangle_indexed.cpp

Comment: But the author then rebinds the VAO in the render loop at line 157.

Comment: @G.M., yeah, that's my misprint. Anyway, It gives me an error after the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is  not a valid enumeration constant for [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml), but it is a proper argument for [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml).
Invoke `glClear`, after the clear color is set by [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml):

```py
class PlyViewportWidget(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget):
    # [...]

    def initializeGL(self):
        
        #gl.glEnable(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) <---- DELETE
        
        gl.glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1)

        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) # <---- ADD
```

---

You missed to create the named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```py
class PlyViewportWidget(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget):
    # [...]

    def initializeGL(self):
        # [...]

        self.vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1) # <--- 
        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)     # <--- 

        self.vbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        self.ebo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.ebo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 3 * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

Comment: thanks for this note, this time I don't see any mentioning of `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and `glEnable` in error output, but I still got plenty of errors  pointing on `glDrawElements` and `glVertexAttribPointer` so I can't see a rectangle on a screen. There should not be any mistakes in it, it would not work in example in other case.

Comment: @Artem You missed `self.vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1);` `gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)`

Comment: But may I Ask you a question, why it was working and didnt throw any errors before the moment I specified the QSurfasceFormat?

Comment: @Artem With a compatibility contexz the default VAO (0) is valid, but with a core profile it is not.